# How do I best pass arguments to a Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl

I have a file, `someFile`, like this:

```
$cat someFile
hdisk1 active
hdisk2 active
```

I use this shell script to check:

```
$cat a.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for d in 1 2
do
    grep -q "hdisk$d" someFile && echo "$d : ok"
done
```

I am trying to convert it to Perl:

```
$cat b.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh
export d
for d in 1 2
do
    cat someFile | perl -lane 'BEGIN{$d=$ENV{'d'};} print "$d: OK" if /hdisk$d\s+/'
done
```

I export the variable `d` in the shell script and get the value using `%ENV` in Perl. Is there a better way of passing this value to the Perl one-liner?

Comment: Why not perform the looping directly in Perl? Then your shell script simply disappears.

Comment: Instead of using `cat file | perl ...` it is more simple to use `perl ... file`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can enable rudimentary command line argument with the "s" switch. A variable gets defined for each argument starting with a dash. The `--` tells where your command line arguments start.

```
for d in 1 2 ; do 
  cat someFile | perl -slane ' print "$someParameter: OK" if /hdisk$someParameter\s+/' -- -someParameter=$d; 
done
```

See: *[perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)*

Comment: Some many thanks. Never really  figured it out. Always wrote a script when needing command line arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes breaking the Perl enclosure is a good trick for these one-liners:

```
for d in 1 2 ; do cat kk2 | perl -lne ' print "'"${d}"': OK" if /hdisk'"${d}"'\s+/';done
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass it on the command line, and it will be available in `@ARGV`:

```
for d in 1 2
do
  perl -lne 'BEGIN {$d=shift} print "$d: OK" if /hdisk$d\s+/' $d someFile
done
```

Note that the `shift` operator in this context removes the first element of `@ARGV`, which is `$d` in this case.

Comment: It is worth point out that @gbacon has converted `cat a| perl -n` to `perl -n a`.  If you give a filename as a parameter to perl it is available to the -n loop.

Answer (score 3):

Combining some of the earlier suggestions and adding my own sugar to it, I'd do it this way:

```
perl -se '/hdisk([$d])/ && print "$1: ok\n" for <>' -- -d='[value]' [file]
```

[value] can be a number (i.e. 2), a range (i.e. 2-4), a list of different numbers (i.e. 2|3|4) (or almost anything else, that's a valid pattern) or even a bash variable containing one of those, example:

```
d='2-3'
perl -se '/hdisk([$d])/ && print "$1: ok\n" for <>' -- -d=$d someFile
```

and [file] is your filename (that is, `someFile`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble writing a one-liner, maybe it is a bit hard for one line (just my opinion). I would agree with @FM's suggestion and do the whole thing in Perl. Read the whole file in and then test it:

```
    use strict;
    local $/ = '' ; # Read in the whole file
    my $file = <> ;

    for my $d ( 1 .. 2 )
    {
        print  "$d: OK\n" if  $file =~ /hdisk$d\s+/
    }
```

You could do it looping, but that would be longer. Of course it somewhat depends on the size of the file.

Note that all the Perl examples so far will print a message for each match - can you be sure there are no duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a little different. I came to your question with a Google search the title of your question, but I'm trying to execute something different. Here it is in case it helps someone:

FYI, I was using [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) on Solaris.

I had the following one-liner:

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime(time()-3600*24*2));'
```

which outputs the value:

```
2013-05-06
```

I was trying to place this into a shell script so I could create a file with a date in the filename, of X numbers of days in the past. I tried:

```
set dateVariable=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime(time()-3600*24*$numberOfDaysPrior));'`
```

But this didn't work due to variable substitution. I had to mess around with the quoting, to get it to interpret it properly. I tried enclosing the whole lot in double quotes, but this made the Perl command not syntactically correct, as it messed with the double quotes around date format. I finished up with:

```
set dateVariable=`perl -e "use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime('%Y-%m-%d', localtime(time()-3600*24*$numberOfDaysPrior));"`
```

Which worked great for me, without having to resort to any fancy variable exporting.

I realise this doesn't exactly answer your specific question, but it answered the title and might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

That looks good, but I'd use:

```
for d in $(seq 1 2); do perl -nle 'print "hdisk$ENV{d} OK" if $_ =~ /hdisk$ENV{d}/' someFile; done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already written on the top in one long paragraph but I am also writing for lazy developers who don't read those lines.

**Double quotes** and **single quote** has big different meaning for the bash.

So please take care

**Doesn't WORK**  `perl '$VAR' $FILEPATH`

**WORKS** `perl "$VAR" $FILEPATH`