# Replace a phrase in a file with a string which contains special Characters

Tags: string, shell, unix, sed

I am using `sed -e "s/foo/$bar/" -e "s/some/$text/" file.whatever` to replace a phrase in a certain file. The problem is that the $bar string contains multiple special characters like `/`. So when I try to replace something in a text file using the following code...

```
#!/bin/bash

bar="http://stackoverflow.com/"

sed -e "s/foo/$bar/" -e "s/some/$text/ file.whatever
```

...then I get an error saying : `sed: unknown option to s` is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any delimiter.  `s@some@SOME@` for example. Another good delimiter is vertical-bar. Other chars can work but have special significance for some contexts such as regular expressions.

Comment: Just to nitpick, `^` is a regex metacharacter, so you'd be better off picking something like `|` or `@`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this difficulty in sed regardless of what delimiters you use, especially if you don't know what the string contains. I'd pick a different method for passing the shell variables into the helper interpreter.

```
awk -v rep1="$bar" -v rep2="$text" '{sub(/foo/, rep1); sub(/some/, rep2); print}'
```

or

```
perl -spe 's/foo/$rep1/; s/some/$rep2/' -- -rep1="$bar" -rep2="$text"
```

Correctness trumps brevity in this case.
([reference for Perl example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322211/7552))