# how can I print with 3 digits in the c shell?

Tags: csh

I'd like to print with 3 digits such as 001, 002, ... not 1, 2, ... in the c shell.

but  when I use the below example, I've got just number without 3 digits.

So I want to know how to print the 3 digits number as 001 not 1.

how can I print it with 3 digits in the c shell?

```
#!/bin/csh -f

 set j = 1
 while ( $j <= 400 )
   echo "Welcome $j times"
   @ j++
 end
```

results

0

1

...

100

...

400

## update

One more question. if I want to assign it as a variance from " printf 'Welcome %03d times' $j" itself.
Like this,

```
 set j = 1
 set k

 while ( $j <= 400 )
   printf 'Welcome %03d times' $j
   k = printf 'Welcome %03d times' $j

   @ j++
 end
```

If I want to assign 3digit number into the k variance like this k=003 not k=3.
what am I do ?

## update2

when I ran the below code, I've got always 000 not increase.

```
 set j = 1 
 while ( $j <= 500 ) 
   echo "Welcome $j times" 
 set k = `perl -e 'print (sprintf ("%03d", $j))'` 
   echo "set k= $k "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for you first question, the answer is as Alexandr wrote:

> #!/bin/csh -f
>
> set j = 1
>    while ( $j <= 400 )
>      printf 'Welcome %03d times' $j
>      @ j++
>    end

for your second question, you can do something like this:

> > set test = `perl -e 'print (sprintf ("%03d", 3))'`
>   > echo $test
>   003

see http://www.brendangregg.com/Guess/guess.csh
in order to pass vars to the perl one liner, see the below line
[How do I best pass arguments to a Perl one-liner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321829/how-do-i-best-pass-arguments-to-a-perl-one-liner)

Comment: When I ran the below code I've got alwasy 000. 
 set j = 1 
 while ( $j <= 500 ) 
   echo "Welcome $j times" 
 set k = `perl -e 'print (sprintf ("%03d", $j))'` 
   echo "set k= $k "

Comment: that is because the $j is not in the perl space, but in the csh space. using $ENV will also not help you because you use `set` instead of `setenv`. try your code with `setenv j 1` and `perl -e 'print (sprintf ("%03d", $ENV{j}))'` instead, it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/csh -f

 set j = 1
 while ( $j <= 400 )
   printf 'Welcome %03d times' $j
   @ j++
 end
```

not sure about csh, but it should work